# Custom sorting for an array of strings

Tags: perl, sorting

I have a text file with several lines

```
abc 122 aaaaaaa
cba 165 aaaaaaaa
aaa 123 aaaaaaaaa
bvc 443 aaaaaaaaaa
rdc 993 aaaaaaaaaaa
qwe 103 aaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Each line contains a decimal number.
Can I sort this lines using decimal number as a marker for a sorting?

I want to do something like this but this code is not working.

```
for my $line (sort @lines {(($a =~ /(\d+)/)[0]) <=> (($b =~ /(\d+)/)[0])}) {
    print $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Store the grouping elements in a temporary variable and perform sort from that variable.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @ar = <DATA>;
my $m;
my $n;
foreach (sort{ ($m)=$a=~/(\d+)/; ($n)=$b=~/(\d+)/; $m <=>$n } @ar)
{
    print "$_";

}


__DATA__
abc 122 aaaaaaa
cba 165 aaaaaaaa
aaa 123 aaaaaaaaa
bvc 443 aaaaaaaaaa
rdc 993 aaaaaaaaaaa
qwe 103 aaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. As well as I. It was an error with wrong order of LIST and BLOCK in `sort`.
Mea culpa.

Answer (score 2):

The `nsort_by` function from [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) wraps this in a much more readable form. It is also fast, because it is written in C

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::UtilsBy 'nsort_by';

my @data = <DATA>;

print for nsort_by { (split)[1] } @data;


__DATA__
abc 122 aaaaaaa
cba 165 aaaaaaaa
aaa 123 aaaaaaaaa
bvc 443 aaaaaaaaaa
rdc 993 aaaaaaaaaaa
qwe 103 aaaaaaaaaaaa
```

#### output

```
qwe 103 aaaaaaaaaaaa
abc 122 aaaaaaa
aaa 123 aaaaaaaaa
cba 165 aaaaaaaa
bvc 443 aaaaaaaaaa
rdc 993 aaaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = ""; # enter your filename 
open FH, $filename or die "Error\n";

my @array   = <FH>;
my @values  = map /(\d+)/, @array;
my @indices = sort { $values[$a] <=> $values[$b] } 0 .. $#values;

print "$array[$_]\n" for @indices;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem in your original code is that you have the arguments to `sort` in the wrong order. `sort` expects an (optional) sort block followed by the list of items to sort. You have the list of items (`@lines`) followed by the sort block. Reversing those will fix your problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = <DATA>;

for my $line (sort {(($a =~ /(\d+)/)[0]) <=> (($b =~ /(\d+)/)[0])} @lines) {
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
abc 122 aaaaaaa
cba 165 aaaaaaaa
aaa 123 aaaaaaaaa
bvc 443 aaaaaaaaaa
rdc 993 aaaaaaaaaaa
qwe 103 aaaaaaaaaaaa
```

As is so often true, adding `use strict` would have shown that there was something wrong here.